# Horizontal RecyclerView below Vertical RecyclerView

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to implement some sort of chat questions(Vertical RecyclerView) and have answers(Horizontal RecyclerView) below the vertical Recyclerview
I have managed to achieve what I had in my mind, however:
What I have now:
vertical rv is working fine, and horizontal rv is on bottom of the view;
What I want to have is:
 Im want to have the answers right below the vertical rv, as it expands, so if the vertical rv has one itemview, it should be right below it, and as it expands until the horiozontal rv reaches the bottom of the view

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/verticalRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

edit xml to

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/verticalRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"     
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"      
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

use code for horizontal recyclerview

```
 LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

RecyclerView myList = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
myList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

and for vertical recyclerview use

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

RecyclerView myList = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
myList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Comment: Doesn't work, there's a lot of empty spaces below the vertical recyclerview even though it has only one item, and once its filled, there are a lot of space below horizontal recyclerview

Comment: you have to set weight for both recyclerview if you set wrap_content then upper recycler view hides lower recyclerview when it contains more item

Comment: Yea but this way, i end up having the horizontal rv in the middle of the layout untill the vertical view is filled then once its filled, there are empty space below the horionztal recyclerview

Comment: What im trying to achieve is having the second recyclerview below the upper one,until the upper is filled then the second recyclerview would stick at the bottom

Comment: then remove weight and set height to wrp_content for both rv.

Comment: I have tried that, once the first rv is filled, it takes up the whole screen and the bottom rv doesn't even fit in the screen

Comment: either you can use weight for both or set wrap_content there is no other option.. sorry

Answer (score 0):

just add the weightsum property for LinearLayout android:weightsum = 1.5 and just ensure in your adapter no empty spaces in adapter if you give also it will affect 
if you agreed my answer please vote

Comment: Please include the actual code on how to do that in your answer so that the asker know how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightsum = "1.5"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/verticalRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"     
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"      
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```